# Using a snapshot as an upstream

Tags: git

I have a git repository that my team has been working on. Let's call it the `main` repo. Now I needed few things done by externals, so I took copy of the files I had in the repository and just made a new one (let's call it `snapshot` repo).

Now both repositories contain some changes, and I'd like git to understand that the `snapshot` repository's starting point is a specific commit of the `main` repo and then merge changes from both repos. Or cherry pick from the `snapshot` and then from time to time push a new snapshot there.

How would you go about it? Or was making a copy already a mistake?

Comment: Trying to sync between repos as if they were branches within the same repo feels like a hack to me.  Is there anything wrong with using a single repository?

Comment: Well mainly I was uncomfortable with making the long git history of a hobby project public.

Comment: Could you create a new branch and then squash down some of the commits?  Cherry picking should be used sparingly, IMO, especially if you ever plan on merging the full source branch at some point.

Answer (score 1):

> Or was making a copy already a mistake?

Yes. You should have done a shallow clone (with an history of 1 commit. But do it with exactly with the commit where you take the snapshot! ) that way, you will be able to share commits because the 2 repository have at least a commit in common.

You could still try to do something using the 'git rebase --onto' if the history 'the externals' did, do not contain merges...

Or a little more difficult, but a better long time solution, do the shallow clone, in a repository, fetch it the existing repository and do a 'git replace' to change the root commit with the new one!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the git toolbox, there is a hidden command which should help with your situation :
[`git replace`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace)

Here is a post explaining how you can use it :
[Replace Kicker](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/17/replace.html)

Here is one way to use it :

```
# start with a clone of your main repo :
git clone myrepo grafting
cd grafting

# add a copy of the 'external' repo as a remote :
git remote add external /path/to/external
git fetch external

# your main repo will be referenced as 'origin', the external repo as 'external'

# * you will need the hash of the original commit from which you created the
#   inital 'external' commit : I will call this commit <base>

# * you need the hash of the first commit on external :
#   I will call this commit <external>
git log --oneline external/master | tail -1

# "replace" the initial commit on external with the commit of your main repo :
git replace <external> <base>
```

You should now be able to use most of git's commands as though `external` was grafted inside `origin`.

---

My advice would be : from this `grafting` directory, build a clean new repo, which you will then use as a reference for both you and the external team.